# "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

Tags: angularjs

I was constantly getting this error while running the command "ng serve". I have made the project externally and have downloaded some files even from an external source. please help me to crack this code . its a request.

Comment: Are you running the command from a folder with angular.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you run the `ng serve` command outside of an Angular project. Make sure that you run that command in the exact folder where your project is located (that's where `angular.json` is located).

Comment: that's right but i have tried this to but the problem remained the same. can you please favour me by reviewing my source code please.

Comment: Does the folder where you're running that command have the ```angular.json``` file?